# Pandas datatable to html with footer

Tags: python, html, pandas

Suppose I output the following data to HTML as:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df.to_html(index = False, header = "true")
```

What I would like is for this to also produce footer information, something like after the `</tbody>` tag at the end.

```
<tfoot>\n     <th>col1</th>\n      <th>col2</th>\n    </tr>\n  </tfoot>
```

The documentation here https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html doesn't suggest a footer option, so curious if there is a workaround?

Many tables are dynamically produced on the fly so hardcoding wouldn't be feasible.

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: Doesn't look like that is supported in to_html. Why not use a dom parser like lxml to create a footer element and insert it into the table?

Answer (score 0):

df.to_html return a str so you can just add it manually.

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df.to_html(index = False, header = "true")\
+"<tfoot>\n" + " ".join(["<th>"+ i +"</th>\n" for i in df.columns])+"</tr>\n  </tfoot>"
```

ouput

```
'<table border="1" class="dataframe">\n  <thead>\n    <tr style="text-align: right;">\n      <th>col1</th>\n      <th>col2</th>\n    </tr>\n  </thead>\n  <tbody>\n    <tr>\n      <td>1</td>\n      <td>3</td>\n    </tr>\n    <tr>\n      <td>2</td>\n      <td>4</td>\n    </tr>\n  </tbody>\n</table><tfoot>\n<th>col1</th>\n <th>col2</th>\n</tr>\n  </tfoot>'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done following in FastAPI

```
import pandas as pd
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse

d = {'A': [1, 2], 'B': [3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

1. Convert df into Table HTML, this make table in string

   ```
   df_into_html = df.to_html(escape=False, index=False, border=0)
   ```
2. Add `<tfoot>` in the above generated Table HTML, `tfoot` has all header names, We need to insert `<tfoot>` before `</table>`. First find index of `</table>`

   ```
   idx = df_into_html.index('</table>')
   ```
3. Insert `<tfoot>` before `</table>` to let `<tfoot>` come inside the table

   ```
   final_table = df_into_html[:idx] + "<tfoot><tr>" + " ".join(["<th>"+ i +"</th>" for i in df.columns])+"</tr> </tfoot>" + df_into_html[idx:]
   ```
4. `print(final_table)`

   ##### Output

   ```html
   <table class="dataframe">
   <thead>
       <tr style="text-align: right;">
       <th>A</th>
       <th>B</th>
       </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
       <tr>
       <td>1</td>
       <td>3</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
       <td>2</td>
       <td>4</td>
       </tr>
   </tbody>
   <tfoot><tr><th>A</th> <th>B</th></tr> </tfoot>
   </table>
   ```